# ORMLite reset all tables

Tags: android, ormlite

I have an application that uses [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/). I need to create a function to reset the entire db (basically I need to delete all rows from every db, reset the autoincrement and reset indexes).

I probably can do this by launching a truncate on every table but does ORMLite has some specific method to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ORMLite does not have a special method to reset the entire db.  It does support the [`TableUtils.clearTable(connectionSource, dataClass))` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#clearTable(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class)) which removes all of the rows from the table, which would clear the index, but this will not reset the auto-increment.  Also, I'm not sure what "reset indexes" implies more than clearing them.  The process of resetting the auto-increment is going to be extremely database dependent so ORMLite will most likely never have native support that anyway.

I think your best bet is to [drop the table using `TableUtils.dropTable()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#dropTable(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean)) and then re-[create it with `TableUtils.createTable()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#createTable(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class)) .

Comment: can the same effect be obtained from dbhelper.onUpgrade(dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(), 0, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION); ?

Comment: Hey @max4ever, I don't think that will do it for you.  You have to implement the `onUpgrae(...)` method so it depends on how you do it.  If your `onUpgrade(...)` drops and then creates then it will work, yes.

Comment: @Gray

to delete primary idx auto inc you can use execRaw() with this SQL:

executeRawNoArgs("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='" + TABLENAME + "';");

Comment: @Gray ... or use update-staement to set field named "seq" to 0 in the same table "sqlite_sequence"

Answer (score 3):

There is one way possible.. delete the database but this method is usually used when user log out and login with another user id etc, at login db is created and at logout db is deleted.

```
mContext.deleteDatabase("xxxxxx");
```

where "xxxxx" is the database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(source,dataClass). Useful when testing.